# Querying Many to Many relationship table with Linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I need help in querying the table with many to many relationship using linq to entities. Below is my scenario: In the below scenario each BName (from Table 2) can have more than one value in Table 3, so how can I query using linq to entities ? to get in the format of below class structures mentioned at last.

Table 1: entityA:
Columns :
entityAId | AName | Description

Table 2: entityB: 
Columns:
entityBId | BName | Description

Many to Many relationship table Table 3:
entityC: 
Columns:
entityCId | entityAId | entityBId | Value

```
public class TempClassA //Corresponds to Table 1
{
    public string AName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<TempCLassB> lstTempClassB { get; set; } 
}

public class TempCLassB //Corresponds to Table 2
{
    public string BName { get; set; }
    public List<String> Values { get; set; }  //Corresponds to Table 3
}
```

Comment: Is this a pre-existing database? If so where did you get these classes from? Have you looked into using Database First/Code First configurations of Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes this is pre-existing database, these classes are user defined classed in C#, once the data is fetched from database using this class objects data is passed.

Comment: Try using the Database First tools to create your mapping classes etc as opposed to (what I assume to be) Code First, since you aren't doing Code First.